# When should one use accept-charset="UTF-8" in an HTML form?

Tags: html, unicode

I'm curious whether there's a usage case for the `accept-charset="UTF-8"` attribute in HTML forms?  It seems it's 100% redundant when the pages are already advertised as utf-8, and it's dis/mis-regarded by some browsers in other cases.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the page is already utf-8 it is redundant, but not 100%.
If the user overrides the encoding of the page, then adding that to the form is an extra safety measure.